Excel Macro Runs With Breakpoint but Fails Without It
I have an Excel macro that opens a workbook and activates the first worksheet, then searches for a specific string in the first row.  If I run the macro without any breakpoints, it fails to find the string but if I set a breakpoint just before the search, it works perfectly.  It's as if the worksheet activation isn't completely finished before the search is run, but setting a breakpoint gives it time to finish.  I've tried the kludgy approach of adding a 3-second wait after activating the worksheet, but that didn't help.
The workbook being opened contains a pivot table, which may be related.  I've read that they are sometimes slow to open.  If I open a different worksheet without a pivot table, it works fine.
Here is an excerpt of the code that is failing.  If I set a breakpoint at the line where the search is done (ColNum = ColWith...), it works.  Without the breakpoint there, it fails.  What can I do to resolve this?
Dim ColNum       As Integer
Dim FileType     As Integer
Dim ImportWB     As Workbook
Dim ImportWS     As Worksheet

Set ImportWB = Workbooks.Open(FullFileName)
Set ImportWS = ImportWB.Sheets(1)
ImportWS.Activate
' <<< Tried waiting 3 seconds here but it did not work

ColNum = ColWith("Commissions", "1:1", xlPart) ' Function searches specified range for specified text
If ColNum > 0 Then
    FileType = 0
Else
    ColNum = ColWith("Residual", "1:1", xlPart) ' <<< This text should be found in the file!
    If ColNum > 0 Then
        FileType = 1
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not find either 'Residual' or 'Commissions' in row 1 of the imported file - Exiting"
    End If
End If


Side note. There's almost never a need to Activate anything. You should likely refactor ColWith so it doesn't rely on a sheet being active.

If your code isn't finding the value it's probably a problem in the ColWith function. Could you edit your question and add the code for that?  You shouldn't have to activate the worksheet, just reference it within the function.

post-script saw ben's note as i was typing this, so he beat me to it.
You don't need to activate, you need to call and qualify your ranges, e.g.:
with importws
    .Range().Find()
    .Cells().Find()
    .Columns().Find()
    .Rows().Find()
end with

Beyond that, you are having VBA convert Integer, whereas you should use Long (small increase in efficiency, but worth noting for longterm usage).
edit
adding a mock-up of another approach:
With ImportWS
    Dim CommissionsRng As Range:  Set CommissionsRng = .Rows(1).Find("Commissions")
    Dim ResidualRng As Range:  Set ResidualRng = .Rows(1).Find("Residual")
    Dim filetype As Long:  Select Case True
        Case Not CommissionsRng Is Nothing 'will exit select if this is met
            filetype = 0
        Case Not ResidualRng Is Nothing
            filetype = 1
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("meh")
     End Select
     Debug.Print filetype
End With


Perhaps a side note, it'd be best to specify the arguments LookIn and LookAt for the two Find calls.

@BigBen Agreed; I gave a quick mock-up how to utilize the qualified ranges, but could probably do a bit more to make it fleshed out..

It turns out that the problem was due to the fact that the Excel file containing the pivot table has some sort of hidden worksheet as worksheet #1.  It had a strange name and could not be unhidden, as far as I can tell.  I don't know if it is related to the pivot table or because the originators had saved this as an "xlsb" file originally.
In any case, I was looking for the text in "ImportWB.Sheets(1)" thinking it was the first visible worksheet, but was in fact this hidden worksheet.
So it had nothing to do with the search function itself.  I worked around this by looking for the worksheet name instead of the number.
